# Is there motivation for a ring with operations $x\oplus y = x+y-u$ and $x\odot y=x+y-u^{-1}xy$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, soft-question

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4476590/620957) is a basic exercise in verifying whether something is a ring or not. In a slightly generalized version, the result is the following:

> Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring, and let $u\in R^*$ be a fixed invertible element. Then $\tilde R=(R,\oplus,\odot)$ with
> $$x\oplus y = x+y-u, \quad x\odot y=x+y-u^{-1}xy$$ is a ring (with $\tilde0=u$, $\tilde1=0$). Also note that $\tilde R$ inherits (at least) commutativity, "integral domain"-ness and field-ness from $R$.

I got curious: Is there any nice motivation for the construction? Is this a natural thing to do/study?

I did note that we can rewrite
$$
x\odot y = -u^{-1}(x-u)(y-u) + u,
$$
which has a nice symmetry to it. Perhaps a geometric interpretation is possible? The sum at least can be seen as the regular sum with the "origin" shifted to $u/2$.

Comment: You may find of interest applications of circle composition when studying Jacobson radicals and related topics, e.g see [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.43/no.1/b43h1eas.pdf). See also [transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure).

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right, that seems to be exactly where it comes from, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing more than [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20in%20universal,with%20a%20pre%2Dexisting%20structure.), which can be done with any bijection from $R$ to another set.  (The wiki article doesn't seem to list transport of algebraic operations as an example right now, but it is indeed called this in practice.)

That is, given a ring $R$, a set $X$ and a bijection $R\to X$, we may declare new operations $\oplus, \otimes$ on $X$ given by

$$
f(x)\oplus f(y):=f(x+y)\\
f(x)\otimes f(y) := f(xy)
$$
and $(X, \oplus,\otimes)$ becomes a ring. Moreover, $f$ is a ring isomorphism between the two.

That is what is happening here, where we are using the bijection $x\mapsto -ux+u$. Since $u$ is assumed invertible (otherwise $u^{-1}$ has no meaning) the assignment is a bijection.

So yes, your intuition that there's some geometric intuition is justified since $-ux+u$ is a scaling followed by a translation inside $R$. The bijection is built purely out of ring operations. But keep in mind that depending on $R$, scaling and translating might be a lot weirder than it is in a nice ordered field like $\mathbb R$.

When you use an arbitrary bijection $f$ I wouldn't say there is any geometric intuition, since the rearrangement could be quite arbitrary.  You could call that geometric but it seems to be more combinatoric at that point.

Comment: Thanks! Is there in general any trick to "extracting" $f$ if one suspects transport of structure is going on? In this case it's straightforward enough to find by assuming an affine transformation. It don't suppose much is possible in general, since even here the addition could be defined by $f(x)=vx+u$ for any unit $v$ (the point being, $f$ may not be unique).

Comment: Oh, I'm being silly. $f$ is nothing more or less than an isomorphism between the two objects of course; any would do. And characterizing isomorphisms is of course very dependent on the situation.

Comment: @Milten In general, yes, it could be nontrivial to deduce, but yes, in this case the operations were just ring operations, so it was a good bet that the map was guessable.  The way I do it is determine $0$ and $1$ in the new operation and then try out the apparent transformation that does that.